# How do I solve "XPC connection interrupted" on iOS 13?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS application that works perfectly on all versions of iOS under 12 , ON iOS 13 it stops responding (crash) when clicking on a button, 
with an error `XPC connection interrupted` , my application uses both objective c and swift languages

Comment: In order to help you,  you should add a crash report to your question.

Comment: XPC connection interrupted is the only crash report

Comment: If you're on iOS, you rarely use XPC directly but rather use it via some framework, and it’s the framework’s responsibility to handle interruptions.  So the actual problem here is a bit of a mystery. We really need the full crash report as the comments above tell you :)

Comment: Deleting the project app on simulator(content and settings if possible), quitting all simulators, quitting xcode worked for me.